# convert string to Dom in vuejs

Tags: html, string, dom, vue.js

recently I want to convert a stirng to Dom in a vue component, but it does't work as my expectation. My code looks like this:

```
  // what I wrote in the template
  <div id="log">
      {{libText}}
  </div>

  // what I wrote in js
        Vue.component(...  , {
        template: ...  ,
        data: function () {
               return ...     
            }
        },
        computed: {           
            libText:function(){
                var str="<p>some html</p>";
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = str;
                return div;
            }
        },
        methods:{...}
        })
```

The result I get is a string "[object HTMLDivElement]" rather than a Dom.
 It would be greatful if anyone can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is:

Template:

```
<div id="log">
    {{{libText}}}
</div>
```

Notice triple {} for get raw html/text interpretation.

Javascript:

```
Vue.component(...  , {
    template: ...  ,
    data: function () {
           return ...     
        }
    },
    computed: {           
        libText:function(){
            // return directly html
            var str="<div><p>some html</p></div>";
            return str;
        }
    },
    methods:{...}
});
```

Answer (score 57):

If you are using Vue 2, use the `v-html` directive:

```
<div v-html="yourVariable"></div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

Comment: It works perfectly even if you want to leave it as string. Thanks!

Comment: worked on Vue 3 too, thanks!