# Vuejs Convert HTML to Plain text

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to convert HTML to plain text using vuejs.

```
<ol>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

I used [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) but this parse HTML sting to HTML like below

```
 1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
 2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
 3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
 4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

But I want result to be like this.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I could do this with [`angularjs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289448/angularjs-to-output-plain-text-instead-of-html) or [`javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) but I couldn't found anything with `vuejs`

**Note:** I'm not using `jquery` in my project.

Comment: Did you tried this question answer -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428220/convert-string-to-dom-in-vuejs

Comment: You know VueJS is JavaScript, right? The JS solution should work.

Comment: @Terry I know, I'm looking for stranded  solution by vue e.g. service or filter, and considering `js` solutions as last option.

Comment: @weBer That question is about converting `string` to `dom`, and I want to convert `html` to `plain text`, not DOM at all, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I don't see why there **must** be a VueJS-ish way to do this. What you are describing is simply pulling the `textContent` of a virtually created DOM node based on the incoming HTML. If native JS can do this, there is no reason why it has to be included as a helper functionality in VueJS. Based on your reasoning, then VueJS should include it's own iterating functions, its own array mapping methods, its own prototype for every type object, and etc. What you can do though, is to create a global helper method that does that for you.

Comment: @Terry I'll try it, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

what about custom directives

```js
Vue.directive('plaintext', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerText;
    //el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <ol v-plaintext>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to convert from css

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    html: `<ol>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
</ol>` 
  }
});
```

```css
ol{
  list-style: none;
}
ol li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <div v-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

Another way using hidden div

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  computed:{
    newHTML: function(){
      document.querySelector("#temp").innerHTML = this.html;
      var textContent = document.querySelector("#temp").textContent;
      document.querySelector("#temp").innerHTML = "";
      return textContent;
    }
  },
  data: {
    html: `<ol>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
    <li>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</li>
</ol>`
  }
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <div>{{newHTML}}</div>
</div>
<div class="hide" id='temp'>123</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but `ol` is just for example, HTML can contain any tag `div`, `pre` etc.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey : can you make live demo/fiddle with exact problem ?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w9ho1v8/1/), I hope it's easy to understand now.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey : Ahh I thought you can easily convert this : https://jsfiddle.net/8w9ho1v8/3/