# How to keep track of parent element in v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to change text inside div elements that contain html tags into actual html. I have a v-for loop which lists all the text items into divs.

```
<li v-for="item in items">
    <div id="description" class="content">{{item.description}}</div>
</li>
```

The whole text just includes the html element rather than turning it into html which is not what I want.

I thought about pumping it through a function that would call `document.innerHTML()` on it but Im not sure how to make the parent have a unique ID to call it on. I'd like to keep track of the parent the item is from with either an unique ID or as some sort of parameter.

Comment: I don't really follow. This _sounds_ like an XY problem. If you want to render raw HTML, use the [v-html directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML). Where does the parent ID come into play here?

Comment: You also might want to look at that: [convert string to Dom in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428220/convert-string-to-dom-in-vuejs)

Comment: hmm and @JayNyxed you both are awesome and that helped a ton. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Answering this for anyone who doesn't read the comments like me :-)

`v-html` will [render an HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) snippet to the page.

The second part of your question involves telling Vue that each element is unique. You do this with a `:key`. These give [Vue's Virtual DOM a unique ID](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) for your element. You can use a unique element in your data for the key or an iteration number.

If you will need to access the ID for something else OUTSIDE of Vue's reactivity, use a [Vue ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

So combining all of that your code becomes:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" ref="myItems">
    <div id="description" class="content" v-html="item.description"></div>
</li>
```

or with a number for the key

```
<li v-for="(item, n) in items" :key="n" ref="myItems">
        <div id="description" class="content" v-html="item.description"></div>
    </li>
```

**Note:** when ref's are used in a `v-for` they produce an array. So in this case `myItems.length == items.length` and `myItems[n]` is a unique reference.

Comment: `myItems[n]` is indeed a unique reference, but keep in mind that it does not necessarily refer to the nth `<li>` in the DOM. Vue does not keep the order of elements in reference arrays synchronized with order in DOM if the DOM changes. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952#issuecomment-280661367